# Logrotate replace log file with a binary one

Tags: logrotate

One of my project is logging in a simple file. This file may grow a lot so I used [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to handle log truncation and rotation with this simple configuration file inside `/etc/logrotate.d`:

```
/home/user/project/log {
    daily
    rotate 4
    compress
    missingok
    copytruncate    
}
```

Logrotate is runned once a day with a simple cron job:

```
$ sudo crontab -l
0 0 * * * sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

It correctly runs, creating the `log.n.gz` files ecc, but the main file becomes a data file:

```
~ project $ file log
log: ASCII text, with escape sequences
~ project $ sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/project
~ project $ file log
log: data
```

Why this behaviour? I tried to replace `gzip` with `bzip2` in the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file, but the result is the same